# How to add support for Landscape mode in existing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, ios8.3

I have implemented an `iOS` application for both `iPhone` & `iPad`, supports only in `Portrait` mode with OS `iOS 7` & above. Now I need to add support for `Landscape` as well, and I do not have much knowledge on `Auto layout and Size Class`. Do I need to create separate `xib's` for `Landscape` mode? Please share your best suggestions and thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into attached screenshot for how to use **SizeClass** for design view in **Portrait** and **Landscape** Mode.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Have a look into this image for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply, Size Classes supports from iOS 8, and my current app needs to support from iOS7 & above.

Comment: Have a look into this link for Size Classes on Earlier iOS Versions

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1

Comment: I checked the above link, and Apple says "The deployment target of the app is earlier than iOS 8" but my app needs to support from iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to add support for navigation
1) In project navigator tab, select your project
2)then select general tab and in Deployment info select checkboxes for device orientation (landscape left and landscape right.)
If you dnt wanna use size classes you can go with Autolayout.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html